# convert and join HLS Segment (ts) video into mp4 using php

Tags: php, join, mp4, http-live-streaming

Hi I am using this tool: https://github.com/Ejz/HLSDownloader to download HLS Video segments from m3u8 playlist into ts files no I don't know how can I join and convert all this `.ts` files with help of m3u8 playlist into an .mp4 file using php

Answer (score 1):

`.ts` files contain media streams inside the [MPEG-TS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) container, while `.mp4` files contain them inside the [MP4 File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) or [ISO Base Media File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_base_media_file_format). The differences between the two formats are substantial and AFAIK there is no PHP library that converts between the two formats.

Fortunately one can very easy convert between the two by using `ffmpeg` (or `avconv`). Here is an example:

```
ffmpeg -i in.ts -c copy out.mp4
```

You can invoke ffmpeg using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).